# PM2 unexpected string error with serverless

Tags: serverless, pm2

When I try to use PM2 for serverless offline, I get the following error message.

```
    0|fhirwork | /tmp/yarn--1652132529763-0.26304909057877546/yarn:3
    0|fhirwork | exec "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node@16/16.14.2/bin/node" "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.18/libexec/bin/yarn.js" "$@"
    0|fhirwork |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    0|fhirwork | 
    0|fhirwork | SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    0|fhirwork |     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    0|fhirwork |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    0|fhirwork |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    0|fhirwork |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    0|fhirwork |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    0|fhirwork |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    0|fhirwork |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/repo/github/rmd-private/fhir-works-on-aws-deployment-rmd/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
    0|fhirwork |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    0|fhirwork |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    0|fhirwork |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `--interpreter /bin/bash` for PM2 solved the issue for me. By default PM2 uses `/bin/sh`